# How to check whether all elements of array are in between two values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays with different values and an if statement that returns `True` or `False` depending on the values in the arrays.

Code:

```
avgs = rotation / speed
if (avgs.all() <= 55.2 and avgs.all() >= 55):  #if all avgs between 55 and 55.2 return false
        return False
elif (avgs.any() >55.2 or avgs.any() < 55):    #if any avgs above 55.2 or below 55 return true
        return True
```

The arrays:

```
[55. 55. 55. 55. 55.]
```

and

```
[95.  55.  55.  55.  55.]
```

The output I get is `True` for both, when the first array should return `False` since all the values are between 55 and 55.2.

Any ideas why this is? I'm thinking it has something to do with the statement comparing both arrays and returning same value for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`np.nadarray.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) state:

```
Returns True if all elements evaluate to `True`.
```

The implication is that the method is generally used with Boolean arrays. If *not* used in this way, you may see all sorts of unintended consequences from that fact `0` is considered `False` and `1` True:

```
np.arange(10).all()  # False
np.ones(10).all()    # True
np.zeros(10).all()   # False
```

Comparison operators of a 1d array versus a number automatically produce Boolean arrays. You can also use the `&` operator to combine multiple comparisons *element-wise*. So you can rewrite your logic:

```
def foo(rotation, speed):
    avgs = rotation / speed
    return ((avgs >= 55) & (avgs <= 55.2)).all()
```

Notice there's no need for an `if` statement here. The result of the `np.ndarray.all` is a Boolean value, i.e. either `True` *or* `False`.

Furthermore, a more succinct way of writing your logic is possible via [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and its `atol` ("absolute tolerance") argument:

```
def foo(rotation, speed):
    avgs = rotation / speed
    return np.isclose(A, 55.1, atol=0.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is correct when used in natural language, however not in python.
The "all" method True returns if all elements is True,
and the "any" method returns True if any element is True.
The shortest way to express what you want is

```
avgs = rotation / speed
if ((55 <= avgs) & (avgs <= 55.2)).all():
    return True
return False
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `return ((55 <= avgs) & (avgs <= 55.2)).all()`.  `all()` will return a scalar boolean value

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for `numpy.all()`, you can see that it evaluates to `True` if all the elements are `True`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html

If the array contains any nonzero numbers, it evaluates to boolean `True`. So `[55., 55., 55., 55., 55]` becomes `[True, True, True, True, True]` and the same for `[95., 55., 55., 55., 55]`

Instead you can do the following:

```
if (np.all(avgs <= 55.2) and np.all(avgs >= 55)): 
    return False
elif (np.any(avgs >55.2) or np.any(avgs < 55)):   
    return True
```